# Satisfiability check of first order logic formula is "unknown" in Z3py

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I'm trying to implement satisfiability checking of a regular expression by converting it into a first-order logic formula based on the following excerpt from [Rex: Symbolic Regular Expression Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/rex-ICST.pdf)

[image]

The problem seems to be that the circular reference(?) of `Acc1` in the last axiom makes it so that Z3 is not capable of terminating and returns with "unknown" after a considerable amount of time. This seems weird to me, since if I understand correctly the second arguments of `Acc0` and `Acc1` are used to guarantee termination by decreasing until reaching a value of 0.

In my case to avoid naming conflicts the goal string is named `w` instead of `s`.

Note: Z3 also fails to return "sat" when a satisfying value (eg. "cc") is asserted to `w`.

Edit: After realizing the need for patterns (underlined parts in the screenshot) I've added them. Sadly Z3 still times out trying to solve this problem. I've looked into strategies but haven't found any that seems to help. It would be great if there was a way to eliminate the quantified formulas with the help of pattern matching.

[image]

```
from z3 import *;

def hd(x):
    return SubString(x, 0, 1)

def tl(x):
    return SubString(x,1,Length(x)-1)

def phi(x):
    return And(
        x >= StringVal('a'),
        x <= StringVal('z')
    )

solver = Solver()

solver.set()

Number = Datatype('Number')
Number.declare('nil') # 0
Number.declare('s', ('prev', Number)) # 1 = s(0), 2 = s(s(0))...
Number = Number.create()
nil = Number.nil
s = Number.s

x = String('x')
y = Const('y', Number)
w = String('w')

Acc0 = Function('Acc0', StringSort(), Number, BoolSort()) # String X Number -> Bool
Acc1 = Function('Acc1', StringSort(), Number, BoolSort()) # String X Number -> Bool

ax0_0 = ForAll( x, Acc0(x,nil) == False , patterns=[Acc0(x,nil)]) # For all(x: Acc0(x, 0) -> False
ax0_1 = ForAll( [x, y], Acc0(x, s(y)) == # For all(x,(y: Acc0(x, s(y)) <=>
    And(    
        Not(x == StringVal('')),               #(x != '' AND
        phi(hd(x)), # 'a' <= head(x) <= 'z' AND
        Acc1(tl(x),y)   # Acc1( tail(x),(y)
    ),
    patterns=[Acc0(x, s(y))]
)

ax1_0 = ForAll( x, Acc1(x,nil) == (x == StringVal('')), patterns=[Acc1(x,nil)]) # For all(x: Acc1(x, 0) <=>(x == ''
ax1_1 = ForAll( [x, y], Acc1(x, s(y)) == # For all(x,(y: Acc1(x, s(y)) <=>
    Or(
        And(                           # (
            Not(x == StringVal('')),   #(x != '' AND
            phi(hd(x)), # 'a' <= head(x) <= 'z' AND
            Acc1(tl(x),y)  # Acc1(tail(x),(y)
        ),                             # )
        x == StringVal('')            # OR(x == ''
    ),
    patterns=[Acc1(x, s(y))]
)

solver.add(
    Acc0(w, s(s(nil))),
    ax1_1,
    ax1_0,
    ax0_1,
    ax0_0
)

print(solver.check())
```

Comment: Quantifiers are hard to deal with for SMT solvers. It's probably getting stuck in some sort of an e-matching loop, never making progress as you expect it to. One way to deal with this is via the use of patterns , see Section 6.1.3 of https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html for details. But quantifiers/patterns are known to be tricky to deal with and quite fragile. Best of luck!

Comment: In the meantime I've realised that the parts underlined in the screenshot are indeed patterns that should be set to aid in e-matching, sadly even this way Z3 times out.

Comment: @alias in the paper the satisfiability check is broken into 2 steps, first a based on pattern matching a quantifier free formula is obtained, which is then attempted to be solved. Are you aware of z3 being potentially configurable for such an approach? I'll attach a screenshot of the matching process to the question

Comment: It's possible to use tactics to eliminate quantifiers from the Python interface. See http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~msagiv/courses/asv/z3py/strategies-examples.htm. In theory, you should be able to apply quantifier-elimination first, and then call the solver. However, I haven't used it myself and my impression is that it's not very easy to use.

Comment: @alias I've tried many combinations of tactics but sadly none worked.
I've noticed that by asserting that there does not exist such a `w` for which the assertions hold returns `unsat` which is partially what I want.
The problem is that this way I don't have the abilty to generate a model.  `unsat_core` returns `[]` even when explicitly enabled. 
I've tried using `prove` but that just defines one of the uninterpreted functions in a way to produce a counterexample no matter what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: I'm not surprised. I don't think SMT solvers are up-to the task for managing this sort of a problem for the time being at least. You might want to use semi-automated systems like Lean, Isabelle, Coq, etc.